# I am getting an error as #NAME? while opening CSV File in excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am facing problem in Excel.

When I am opening my CSV file in Excel 2016 then I am getting `#NAME?` error

The formula I am using before converting the CSV file is:

```
=concatenate("+",substitute("A2"," ","+"))
```

and the output I am getting XLSX file as `+ab+c`

where A2 has value as ab c

But when I converting the same file into CSV and reopen the file then the output will change and gives as `#NAME?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary of my exchanges with OP in comments section.

I see basically three solutions (although the third one does not meet the criteria of the OP, but I add for completeness):

1. Do not "open" the CSV file, but import (in an existing or new workbook):  `Data > Get External Data > From Text`, then you go through the import steps (choose your delimiter, which will be `,` in your case), and then you have to define all columns as `TEXT` (this is the most important step, see screenshot below). This is a 100% foolproof solution.
2. Instead of using Excel, you could use another CSV viewer (I understood from OP that a colleague needs to inspect the file before sending onward). This might of course not be feasible in larger organizations where one is not allowed to use other tools, or if the colleague is not cooperative.
3. One can modify the formula so the output becomes `="+ab+c"`. When this is saved in CSV and imported again into Excel, it will just show `+ab+c` on the screen. But for OP the text in the CSV file must be just `+ab+c`, so therefore will not work.

Just a final remark, I could not (using Excel 2013 for Windows 10) replicate the behavior as observed by the OP.  `+ab+c` in a CSV file never gave the `#NAME?` error for me when I opened the file; however, once I *clicked* in the cell, Excel would not let me `ENTER` it, unless I added a `'` to indicate it was text; but I still could `ESC` and leave the cell alone).

I did not do any exhaustive testing, but I observed the following :

- if the text starts with `=` you get the error always (except if followed by a text string in double quotes `"..."`);
- if it starts with `+` or `-`, there must be another operator and number also. So `+ab+3` gave an error, but `+b1+a` not.

So maybe the behavior of Excel is different across versions, or any other settings influence this.

Just to illustrate, herewith a screenshot from the Text Import Wizard (which you find under `Data > Get External Data > From Text`. And in this final step (actually, you still get another step where you have to define where Excel has to put the text, either in a new worksheet, or in an existing worksheet) you have to select all columns (with shift or ctrl) and select `Text` as the `Column data format`.

[image]

Comment: K.Still not solved my problem. Can you share me some screenshot?

Comment: nope, not work yet. once I reopen it after all of the above step doing it still display #NAME?.

Comment: @Arvind As I mentioned above, a CSV file is a text file, and *every time* you **open** a text file in Excel this will happen. If you want to consult/read/check this file *as a text file* in Excel, you have to force Excel to act as a text-reader, hence use `import from text` and define all columns as text (as in described in my answer). Not just once, but every time, and not only you, but also every other colleague who wants to check a text file with Excel. I understood from one of your comments on your question that it does work for you when you do the `Data > Get External Data > From Text` ?

Comment: thanks Peter for your suggestion and effort. If I did not open again and directly upload it works.

Comment: @Arvind You're welcome. And I understand the confusion. A CSV file in windows is often (by default, if Excel is installed) associated with Excel instead of Notepad, so the icon that is associated with the file looks very similar to a *real* Excel file. But this is wrong, it has nothing to do with Excel. A CSV file is a pure text file ! It is just used (a.o.) to store or exchange data records between programs, where each field is separated with a comma (although it could also be a semicolon or other separator, while still having the CSV extension), and each record is on a new line.